# AWS cloudformation : how to properly create a redis cache cluster

Tags: redis, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I want to create an elasticache instance using redis.

I think that I should use it "cluster mode disabled" because everything will fit into one server.
In order to not have a SPOF, I want to create a read replica that will be promoted by AWS in case of a failure of the master.
If possible, it would be great to balance the read only operations between master and slave, but it is not mandatory.

I created a functioning master/read-replica using the aws console then used cloudformer to create the cloudformation json conf. Cloudformer has created me two unlinked  `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster`, but by reading the doc. I don't understand how to link them... For now I have this configuration:

```
{
    "cachehubcache001": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster",
      "Properties": {
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": "true",
        "AZMode": "single-az",
        "CacheNodeType": "cache.t2.small",
        "Engine": "redis",
        "EngineVersion": "3.2.4",
        "NumCacheNodes": "1",
        "PreferredAvailabilityZone": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "Az1B"]},
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sun:04:00-sun:05:00",
        "CacheSubnetGroupName": {
          "Ref": "cachesubnethubprivatecachesubnetgroup"
        },
        "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "sgiHubCacheSG",
              "GroupId"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "cachehubcache002": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster",
      "Properties": {
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": "true",
        "AZMode": "single-az",
        "CacheNodeType": "cache.t2.small",
        "Engine": "redis",
        "EngineVersion": "3.2.4",
        "NumCacheNodes": "1",
        "PreferredAvailabilityZone": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "Az1A"]},
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sun:02:00-sun:03:00",
        "CacheSubnetGroupName": {
          "Ref": "cachesubnethubprivatecachesubnetgroup"
        },
        "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "sgiHubCacheSG",
              "GroupId"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
}
```

I know that it is wrong, but I can't figure out how to create a correct replica. I can't understand the AWS doc, for a start I can't figure out which Type I should use between:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html

Since cloudformer created `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster` I'll go with it, but I've got the feeling that it should have created only one resource, and used the `NumCacheNodes` parameter in order to create two resources.

redis can't use:

- `NumCacheNodes`
- `AZMode` and `PreferredAvailabilityZones`

so I don't know how to make this solution multi-AZ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to do this using `AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup`, the `NumCacheClusters` parameter provide the possibility to have numerous servers. Beware : it seem that you have to handle the connection to master/slave yourself (but in case of a master's failure, aws should normally detect it and change the dns of a slave to permit you point do not change your configuration). here is a sample :

```
"hubElastiCacheReplicationGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "ReplicationGroupDescription" : "Hub WebServer redis cache cluster",
        "AutomaticFailoverEnabled" : "false",
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade" : "true",
        "CacheNodeType" : "cache.t2.small",
        "CacheParameterGroupName" : "default.redis3.2",
        "CacheSubnetGroupName" :  { "Ref": "cachesubnethubprivatecachesubnetgroup" },
        "Engine" : "redis",
        "EngineVersion" : "3.2.4",
        "NumCacheClusters" : { "Ref" : "ElasticacheRedisNumCacheClusters" },
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow" : "sun:04:00-sun:05:00",
        "SecurityGroupIds" : [ { "Fn::GetAtt": ["sgHubCacheSG",  "GroupId"] } ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: How to set the name?

Comment: I found it. is `ReplicationGroupId`